# Zen Cart Link displays constant name rather than value of constant

Tags: php, zen-cart

I have  a site in zen cart, and all works fine.

I have a footer, and want to add in a new link. The constant for this link is defined in a seperate file as

```
define('BOX_INFORMATION_RETURNS', 'Returns');
```

And in my footer menu defines as

```
Define('RETURNS', '<li><a href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_RETURNS, '', 'SSL') .'">' . BOX_INFORMATION_RETURNS . '</a></li>');
```

However when the footer is rendered, all the other constants are replaced witht their values (presumably because they are defined elsewhere), but this one doesnt render, leaving the link with the title BOX_INFORMATION_RETURNS. (Although the url is correct, so it is just the text that it is struggling with.

If I put the Define ('RETURNS' line in the sidebar then it all works. So I suspect that I may need to include a path in the footers section somehow, or that I need to move the file that defines BOX_INFORMATION_RETURNS into a different place, adn the template is not finding it as an override.

However I have no real knowledge of ZenCart, and have not touched PHP in years, so I can't figure out the actual fix.

Comment: is that file which has constant define, is included successfully?

Comment: I suspect not. I don't know where it has to be explicitly included, or if csszend automaticaly scans certain folders for extensions and user templates to override its base ones

Comment: Managed to get round this by including teh extra page. I am sure its not the 'right' way of doing it, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

Because this link shows up in your footer, the define for it needs to be available to all pages at load time.  Possible places for this define

```
define('BOX_INFORMATION_RETURNS', 'Returns');
```

would then be:

- includes/languages/YOUR_TEMPLATE/english.php  (add this line to your language file changes)
- includes/extra_configures/returns.php  (new file with just this line)